# How to use an OR statement with pythons regex sub function?

Tags: python, regex

I want to capitalize the first letter of the string and the letter after every space.

This seems like it should work:

```
re.sub(r'^(.) | \s(.)', lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), "hello world")
```

It returns 'hello world' every time.

If I just use  `^(.)`  or `\s(.)`  it works fine but combining the two with the or pipe causes issues.

How can I harness the sub function to allow use of or statements?

Comment: One quick (don't know how robust) solution: you could lose the spaces in your pattern: `'^(.)|\s(.)'`.

Comment: Why don't you use the string method `title()`?

Comment: CristiFati....yup, that was it.  Derped it big time. Thanks much for the assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex `r'^(.) | \s(.)'` does not work because of the literal spaces contained within it.

You can delete those spaces:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^(.)|\s(.)', lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), "hello world")
'Hello World'
```

Or, you can use the [re.X](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X) flag to ignore those spaces:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^(.) | \s(.)', lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), "hello world", flags=re.X)
'Hello World'
```

In such a case, you should replace `(.)` with a `([a-z])` so you are actually capturing a word-like lower-case character rather than just any character such as the [second space](https://regex101.com/r/fhIrTD/1/) of multiple spaces:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^([a-z]) | \s([a-z])', lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), "hello    world", flags=re.X)
'Hello    World'
```

Or, use a `\b` [word boundary](https://regex101.com/r/yixsVQ/1/) zero-width assertion:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\b(\w)', lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), "hello world")
'Hello World'
```

Or, (simpler and faster) use `.title()`:

```
>>> 'hello    world'.title()
'Hello    World'
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey Using a word boundary is more efficient what using an OR operator. If a better solution exists, why not propose it? +1.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Not directly answering the question can be fine too when the question is an XY problem.

Comment: This site really does confuse me sometimes. I don't understand how the answer above gets five upvotes while this one only gets two. This is the correct regex. There is no point in fixing broken patterns if a better one can be provided.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the alternative answer!  That's a much more succint regex and I added that to my toolbox in my brain.  Was just trying to figure out what I was doing wrong with the above regex and it turned out....spaces. I totally derped it. Thanks again for the alternative way. I kind of disagree no need to answer the question if a better solution can be provided.  It's a learning process and demonstrating what is incorrect with their solution is just as valuabl as providing a better solution as far as the learning process for people goes in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah exactly!  Like no harm in answering the question then also providing a better answer.  That's actually the most ideal way! Either way you guys rock and your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yes, that is also true, although that was originally posted as a comment by Casimir.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: I edited my answer to address your comments. Hopefully that addresses your concerns.

Comment: It does! Guess it's time to commence the comment section clean-up operation.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Thank you for being assertive and STATING why you down voted vs just a silent dv. SO is better with active editing. My answer is better with your input.

Answer (score 3):

You have too many extra spaces in your regex, you can just use this:

```
^(.)|\s+(.)
```

Spaces in regex matters. If you have a space, that means you want to match literal one space character

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UbKILE/2)

Depending on your situation, [`str.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) might be a better solution to your problem.

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar!  This was it!  Thank you!

Comment: @NickKiermaier For a more efficient pattern, see dawg's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this if you're triggering after spaces - just use the .title() function of the string class and a list comprehension to keep it one line if you need to.  You can alternatively break this into a for loop if you're not comfortable with list comprehensions.

```
newstr = ' '.join([word.title() for word in input_string.split()])
```

And the result is:

```
input_string = "hello world"
newstr = ' '.join([word.title() for word in input_string.split()])

print(newstr)
```

'Hello World'

In a for loop it's similar:

```
new_list = []
for word in input_string.split():
    new_list.append(word.title())
new_str = ' '.join(new_list)
```

Comment: You don't need to split a string by space before applying the title method. `"hello world".title()` returns `"Hello World"`

Comment: That's a completely obvious solution that should have clicked in my brain, haha - thanks!

Comment: Hey thanks! I was aware of this and the idea of using a split/capitalize as well, was just tinkering with regex for learning.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. They explicitly asked (twice!) how to use the regex OR operator and why it doesn't work. Offering a better solution is fine and dandy, but you still need to actually answer the question the OP asked. If the question had been "How can I capitalize each word in this string?", your answer would be perfectly acceptable. But it's not.

Comment: That's a fair critique @Aran-Fey - thanks for the feedback.